# Window resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, window-resize, hamburger-menu

I have created a hamburger menu, which drops down fine, but if I maximize the window again, the ul lists remain hidden as they maintain the "display none" status. 
I know I should add a window resize function, but I am not sure how.
How can I fix this?

This is the coding:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('.nav-btn').on("click", function() {
     $('.hamburger').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On resize if window width is bigger than 992 will remove styles added.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  
  if($(window).width() > 992) {
    $(".hamburger").removeAttr("style");
  }
  
});
```